# Unable to read a binary coded hexadecimal value

Tags: c++, pointers, binary, hex, type-conversion

I am reading a binary coded hexadecimal value from the pointer *p.

**The hexadecimal value is:** 2001:0db8:3c4d:0015:0000:0000:abcd:ef12.

**The corresponding binary value is:** 00100000000000010000110110111000001111000100110100000000000101010000000000000000000000000000000010101011110011011110111100010010

```
char *mMmapBase;   
mMmapBase = (char *) mmap( 0, mCollectionFileSize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
            MAP_SHARED, fileno( aFilePtr ), 0 );

char *p = &mMmapBase[107]; //read from the offset 107
int aTwoBytes;
memcpy(&aTwoBytes, p, 2); //copy first two bytes 

cout << "aTwoBytes : " << aTwoBytes << endl;
```

I should get the output either in the hexadecimal form or in the binary form, But, I am getting the following output - aTwoBytes : 539492652. Can anyone tell me why?

Also, I want the output in the hexadecimal form how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you print it as decimal. You might also be mixing the presentation of values (like decimal, hexadecimal, etc.) with how values are stored in the computer (which is always in binary).

If you want to print a hexadecimal number, then you have to use the [`std::hex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex) [iostream manipulator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip):

```
std::cout << "aTwoBytes : " << std::hex << aTwoBytes << '\n';
```

You might also get a "weird" value because you are copying a 16-bit value into a 32-bit variable. Instead of `int` you might want to use `uint16_t` (which on most platforms is the same as `unsigned short`). For this you might need to include [`<cstdint>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer):

```
std::uint16_t aTwoBytes;
```

Comment: So, what is stored in the variable aTwoBytes. Is it a hexadecimal/binary value?

Comment: I need to use the value stored in variable aTwoBytes , so I need to know what is been stored in this variable

Comment: @Prats It's binary, always binary. When you have e.g. `int foo = 0x10;`, then it's the binary value `00010000` that is stored in `foo`. Hexadecimal is just a way of presenting values, values are never stored in it.

Comment: What if I need to extract next two bytes??

Comment: I am extracting next two bytes as: memcpy(&addr2, (p >> 16), 2); but it is giving error

Comment: @Prats Simply increase `p` by two, and do the same. Should probably be done in a loop `for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i, p += 2) { memcpy(...); std::cout ...; }`

Comment: In a loop i am able to take only two bytes values at a time in a variable, but I need to take all 2 bytes into variables, i,e I am having 8 variables and I need to two-two bytes in each variable

Comment: @Prats Then just increase `p` by two between each `memcpy`. You can also use normal assignment by the way: `std::uint16_t value1 = *static_cast<std::uint16_t*>(p); std::uint16_t value2 = *static_cast<std::uint16_t*>(p + 2);` etc.

Comment: One last thing, why 0db8 is coming as db8? Why 0 is not displayed

Comment: @Prats Check the iostream manipulator link in my answer. There should be two that you need to use (hint: they have to do with filling and width).

Comment: Hey, I used this:  unsigned short value1 = *(static_cast<unsigned short*>(p)); but it is giving the following error:  invalid static_cast from type `char*' to type `short

Comment: @Prats Sorry, my bad. You need to use `reinterpret_cast` instead.

Comment: Yes, its the same code. The only change is u told to use uint16_t but I have used unsigned short.  But, I am getting the error

Comment: Used this: unsigned short value1 = *(reinterpret_cast<unsigned short*>(p)); but getting error: Bus Error (core dumped)

Comment: @Prats It may be because you're doing unaligned access to get the data from `p`. You might want to stick with the `memcpy`.

Comment: Ok I will use memcpy,thanks a lot for your precious time. Could you suggest me how to convert the bytes which I stored in 8 variables into hexadecimal and save the hexadecimal form into variables

Answer (score 0):

Because it is printing it in decimal.

Need to learn about numbers and bases - See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix